# Choosing specific ArcSDE version to create replica geodatabase from?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, replication

I'm trying to automate the process of exporting a replica geodatabase using the geoprocessing tools and eventually a Python script.

I can't figure out how to create the replica from a specific version.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've wrote similar python code what your trying to do.  Try the following:

1. Check current version using [Describe/Workspace properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000002v000000)
2. [Create ArcSDE Connection File](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000pt000000) to connect to version you want to replicate
3. Replicate version using [Create Replica](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000016000000)

Hope that helps.